# Speech recognition issue in bot

Tags: botframework, speech-recognition

I am working in bot framework and enabled speech in it.
When testing the speech functionality it is not recognizing few words like "HR".
I tried with different region's subscription key (Westus, eastus, common). In all the cases it is not recognizing word "HR".
How to make it recognize that word?

Is there any option?

```
speechOptions = {
                    speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({
                        subscriptionKey:
                            '*******************'
                    }),
                    speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer({
                        gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,
                        subscriptionKey: '***********************',
                        voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaRUS)'
                    })
                };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe this is possible at the moment. There is currently an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1515) on the Web Chat repo to add support for Biased Word Lists for Speech. Hopefully, it should be prioritized in the 4.6 release. I know the development is beginning to focus on creating a better user experience for speech in Web Chat.

In the meantime, you could prompt your use to phrases like "Human Resources" instead of "HR."

Hope this helps!